# Animate a custom property's value?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can easily animate something like the `position` or `size` of a UIView. But how can I animate a "custom" variable (such as `experiencePoints`) to achieve interpolation of values that are *not* associated with a UIView.

```
// The variable being animated
CGFloat experiencePoints = 0;

// Pseudo-code
[experiencePoints animateTo:200 duration:2 timingFunction:someTimingFunction];
```

With this code, if I accessed `experiencePoints` while it was animating, I would get a value between `0` and `200` based on how long the animation has been going.

Bonus question: Is it possible to use a CAAnimation to do what I want?

Comment: The short answer is you can't. What do you even mean by animating a property's value anyway? Do you mean the string representation of its value in a label or other UI element? The only way to do that is to increment the value using a timer or recursive call to the method that displays the value.

Comment: You can do this for custom CALayer properties. Interested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [Facebook's POP animation library](https://github.com/facebook/pop), which allows the animation of any property on an object. I recommend it!

Here is a quote from the readme, explaining how to do it:

> The framework provides many common layer and view animatable properties out of box. You can animate a custom property by creating a new instance of the class. In this example, we declare a custom volume property:

```
prop = [POPAnimatableProperty propertyWithName:@"com.foo.radio.volume" initializer:^(POPMutableAnimatableProperty *prop) {
  // read value
  prop.readBlock = ^(id obj, CGFloat values[]) {
    values[0] = [obj volume];
  };
  // write value
  prop.writeBlock = ^(id obj, const CGFloat values[]) {
    [obj setVolume:values[0]];
  };
  // dynamics threshold
  prop.threshold = 0.01;
}];

anim.property = prop;
```

Comment: Would be great if you could elaborate on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with Presentation layer with CADisplayLink and by adding observer on animation status you can increment the variable upto your final one. Observer will observe current status of Animation which will eventually provide you a way to get current value of that VAR.

Answer (score -2):

"Animating" something is simply moving a value from a starting position to an ending position over time. To "animate" a float from one value to another over a duration you could just run a timer and incrementally change it. Or possibly you could store the begin and end time of the "animation" and whenever the value is accessed, compare those to the actual time to come up with a value.